# Add date for each ID in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table "Users" that looks like this

```
  id     name
  1      Johny 
  2      Michael
  3      Jony
```

i want add new column called date,

```
date
2021-01-01
2021-02-01
```

but i want the date for each id

```
  id     name      date
  1      Johny     2021-01-01
  1      Johny     2021-02-01
  2      Michael   2021-01-01
  2      Michael   2021-02-01
  3      Jony      2021-01-01
  3      Jony      2021-02-01
```

How to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemingly you're wanting to do a cross join between an existing table, `users` and either another table, or some pseudo table.

Here's how to do it with a pseudo table (I've aliased as `d`)

```
select u.id, u.name, d.date
from
  users u
  cross join
  (
     select TO_DATE('2021-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as date
     union
     select TO_DATE('2021-02-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  ) as d;
```

[Sql Fiddle example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8dcdc/5)

This will produce all permutations (#users x #dates) between the two tables

Comment: Unrelated, but: the UNION part can be simplified to `(values (date '2021-01-01'), (date '2021-02-01')) as d(date)`